# Python Pandas Code is corrupting my excel files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to append a column to an excel file obtained from a .txt file. I also want to retain the formatting and append it to sheet 2 column 1 of said file. I believe I have all that right. However I currently keep corrupting the file somehow so I must be doing something wrong somewhere. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

input_txt_file = r'C:\Users\jcusick\Downloads\TESTextract.txt'
output_xls_file = r'C:\Users\jcusick\Downloads\TESTextract.xlsx'
output_file_path = r'C:\Users\jcusick\Downloads\Functional Validation - System - DDMonth (1).xlsx'

def convert_txt_to_xls(input_txt_file, output_xls_file):
    data = pd.read_csv(input_txt_file, delimiter='\t')
    data.to_excel(output_xls_file, index=False)
    print(f"Converted {input_txt_file} to {output_xls_file}")

def Functional_Checksheet():
    if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
        existing_data = pd.read_excel(output_file_path, sheet_name='Checksheet', engine='openpyxl', header=None)
    else:
        existing_data = pd.DataFrame()
    
    new_df = pd.read_excel(output_xls_file, engine='openpyxl', header=None)
    sorted_data = new_df.sort_values(by=new_df.columns[2], ascending=True)
    existing_data.insert(loc=0, column='NewColumn', value=sorted_data.iloc[:, 2])
    
    # Load the existing workbook using openpyxl
    book = load_workbook(output_file_path)

    # Get the writer object from Pandas
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        writer.book = book
    

    # Write the DataFrame data without headers to the specified sheet
    existing_data.to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=4, startcol=0, header=False, sheet_name='Checksheet')
    
    # Save the workbook
    writer.save()
    print("The file has been converted.")

convert_txt_to_xls(input_txt_file, output_xls_file)
Functional_Checksheet()
```

I would be able to test more if I didn't have to redownload the workbook every time as it gets corrupted. If it would help I can show the column I'm trying to move but it is really just a column of sorted numbers ascending. Part of me thinks it is the format of the file I'm trying to append to which I can also show as needed.